How to find best matching anchor texts from paragraph and list of titles?
I have a paragraph:
In today's world, keeping your personal information safe online is more important than ever. With cyber-attacks on the rise, having a strong cybersecurity strategy is essential. 
Whether it's protecting against viruses or securing your passwords, everyone needs to be vigilant. Understanding the digital threats out there can help you stay one step ahead. Building a resilient defence means using antivirus software and keeping your software updated. It's also important to be aware of phishing scams and suspicious emails. By investing in your cybersecurity, you can protect yourself and your data from harm. So, take the time to learn about online safety and protect your digital life.

And some other articles titles:
titles = [
    "Keeping Your Data Safe: Building a Strong Cybersecurity Strategy",
    "Navigating the Online Minefield: Understanding Digital Threats",
    "Securing Your Online World: Navigating the Cybersecurity Landscape",
    "Strengthening Your Shield: Building a Resilient Cyber Defense",
    "Beyond the Basics: Exploring Advanced Cybersecurity Techniques",
    "Know Your Enemy: Understanding the Cyber Threat Landscape",
    "Protecting Your Digital Fort: Strengthening Ransomware Resilience",
    "Building Trust Online: Enhancing Customer Confidence in Your Security",
    "Compliance in Cybersecurity: Meeting Regulatory Standards for Online Safety",
    "Safeguarding Your Future: Investing in Cybersecurity for Peace of Mind",
]

I want to find the best matching anchor text and title to add internal links.
For example:
1. 
Anchor Text: Cybersecurity Strategy
Title: "Keeping Your Data Safe: Building a Strong Cybersecurity Strategy"

2.
Anchor Text: Security Landscape
Title: "Securing Your Online World: Navigating the Cybersecurity Landscape"

How can I do that? Can someone help me how can I achieve this programmatically?
Edit 1
I want to find a **List of the Best Anchor Texts and Article Titles to add internal links.
Edit 2
I have a website, where users post new articles every day. My Problem is that, while posting a new article, there might be chances that I have already written an article on some phrase or word. I want to suggest phrases, article titles and links to the user so that he can check and add internal links for better SEO.

Are you looking for a programmatic solve here or you want to do it in a search engine (Elasticsearch). Your question is ambiguous, please clarify if you don't have Anchor Text and Article Title and want them to be generated. Since you don't have that information, I'll recommend looking towards some LLM for generation part of it and then building internal links programmatically.

@Aadhar Bhatt I have updated my question as Edit 2. Solution will be ok for me.

What you need to do is first extract the potential concepts (i.e. the anchor texts) that could act as link from your paragraph using techniques such as the ones explained here: https://www.oncrawl.com/technical-seo/automatically-extract-concepts-keywords-from-text-traditional-methods/. Once you have them, it's pretty easy to find the related links using the method provided in the answer. There are many others, but HTTP406 demonstrated that it would work for your use case.
